# Perform Findbugs check on changed files when committing to SVN automatically

Tags: maven, findbugs

Is there a way to perform Findbugs check automatically on files which are going to be committed to SVN?I know there is a Maven plugin, but I don't want to perform a fully scan every time when committing.

Comment: Are you using an IDE, and if so, which one? IDEA has an option to verify changed files and warn about found warnings before commiting, I think it could be used with Findbugs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Eclipse Indigo. Is there any plugin to achieve the same effect in Eclipse?